# Websocket connection is closing immediately for iOS 5 , I am trying to connect to node.js server and phonegap application

Tags: node.js, ios5, cordova, websocket

I am trying to connect to node.js server using websocket. I am developing a Phonegap application. When I try to connect using iOS 6.x simulator it connects to the server through websocket perfectly. But using iOS 5.x simulator it is not connecting. I saw that when I ran the code it was immediately calling the onclose method using ios 5.x simulator. I am using node.js version 0.10.17 and also tried with 0.10.7.

I installed the websocket module for node.js and here is my client side code for connection

```
function openConnection()
{
    // if user is running mozilla then use it's built-in WebSocket
    window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;

    // if browser doesn't support WebSocket, just show some notification and exit
    if (!window.WebSocket)
    {
        alert("Sorry your browser does not support websockets");
        return;
    }
    // new socket

    connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1337'); //change the ip address for online


    // push a message after the connection is established.

    connection.onopen = function()
    {   
        connection.send(sender_id); //change this iuserID in real case.
        //connection.send('Sample1');

        var message ="receive_offline_messages";    
        var message_to_be_sent = JSON.stringify({recevieruserid:sender_id,message:message});
        connection.send(message_to_be_sent);

        //Is the receiver online / offline
        var message ="get_delivery_report"; 
        var message_to_be_sent = JSON.stringify({message_sender_id:sender_id,message:message});
        connection.send(message_to_be_sent);

        connected_to_the_server=1;

        get_unsent_message();
        change_unsent_message_status();


    };
}

.....
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5 implements an early [draft version of the WebSocket spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76).

Most current server based websocket servers only support the finalized WebSocket Spec ([RFC-6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455))

Seen as the following header in the HTTP Upgrade Request Handshake ...

```
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

Also, this site tracks the websocket support level for many browsers.

http://caniuse.com/websockets

Comment: Hello Joakim , thanks for the reply. I am kind newbie in this field but I have understood from your reply that iOS 5 implements earlier version of websocket. But is there any work around or phonegap plugin to work the websocket for iOS 5.x . Specially it will be great if one code works for iOS 5.x and later.